# Can't map Esperanto characters to <kdb>Alt</kbd> Gr in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (Trusty Tahr)

Tags: shortcut-keys

In previous versions on Ubuntu, I was able to type *Esperanto* characters with the <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd> (right alt) key. I think it was under Keyboard > Shortcuts > Esperanto circumflexes.

In Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (Trusty Tahr) this seems to have disappeared.

Where is it in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (Trusty Tahr)?

Comment: See my answer here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/608006/how-to-enable-esperanto-typing-in-trusty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you want to do is add ĉ, ĝ, ĥ, ĵ, ŝ, and ŭ (and the capital versions) to your keyboard in the third (and fourth) positions, i.e., altgr+c=ĉ, shift+altgr+c=Ĉ, you can edit a file in /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols. You want to edit the file for the country whose keyboard you use, so for me it would be /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/us. (You will have to edit the file using sudo.)

You can assign up to four characters per key (normal, 1 ; shift, ! ; altgr, ¡ ; shift+altgr, ¹).

So for example, in the us file you would change

```
key <AB03> { [ c, C ] }
```

to

```
key <AB03> { [ c, C, ccircumflex, Ccircumflex ] }
```

The syntax remains the same: jcircumflex Jcircumflex, etc. And the accent on ŭ is a breve accent, so change that one to ubreve and Ubreve.

When you are done you will have to cd /var/lib/xkb/ and sudo rm *.xkm and then reboot or just log out and back in.

There is likely a more simple way to do what you want, but I know this way works, since it's a part of how I made my own (ridiculously) modified keyboard layout.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I couldn't get it to work. After changing the character like above (and deleting those other files, then rebooting),  nothing is printed with the altgr + c combination.

Comment: Which actual keyboard layout are you using? Be sure to scroll down to your actual keyboard withing the us file. The first set of characters is just the standard English (US) keyboard, and then English (US, international with dead keys), and so on.

Also, I'm not sure if this matters, but I got this to work using UIM input method, so if you're using something else the process _may_ be different.

Comment: I'm just using Finnish. In the Finnish map, there are two layouts. I've changed just the C character in both to test with. Here a pastebin of the fi file: http://pastebin.com/QjJ8cvpg 

I'm not sure what UIM input is compared to the other ways of keyboard input.

Comment: Okay, so I tried what I told you to do and it didn't work for me either. I saw one of the cyrillic languages using UTF-32(hex) so I assumed that was the syntax it wanted for strange characters. Maybe that's still true and we're just missing an "include" or something, but it doesn't matter. I got it to work on mine by using "ccircumflex" and "Ccircumflex" etc. I made sure all the accents work. So here's what my fi looks like now: [http://pastebin.com/i6Zap4q8](http://pastebin.com/i6Zap4q8). (I only changed the first group.) Hopefully that works for you!

Comment: Thanks Matt, it did indeed work. Perhaps you could edit your answer to include ccircumflex and Ccircumflex. I'll mark it as accepted to help others.

Comment: Glad I could help! I also found that you don't have to reboot to reset the symbols file, just log out and back in. I'll edit that too.

Comment: Also in your particular case (if you're using the first group under Finnish) you replaced ssharp (ß) with scircumflex, so if you need that character you might want to put it somewhere else.