# How to enable Esperanto typing in Trusty?

Tags: 14.04, keyboard, keyboard-layout

How do I type Esperanto in Ubuntu 14.04 (Trusty)?

I found many pages showing how to do it enabling the  `Adding Esperanto Circumflexes (Supersigno)` in Keyboard layout settings. But **none of them works in Trusty, although it works fine in Precise**.

Here one example of guide that shows up how to do it: http://zaemis.blogspot.com.br/2012/01/esperanto-accented-characters-in-linux.html

`Adding Esperanto Circumflexes (Supersigno)` allows you type Esperanto easily no matter which keyboard layout you are using or others stuffs. So ***how to activate it on Trusty?***

It should be easy because many people of Esperanto community uses Linux as they share the same ideas of freedom, but they aren't advanced users (don't expect them to use a command line).

(Here is a screenshot of my Text Entry settings. The keyboard settings leads to other panel that only allows to set up key bindings. There is no *Options* button.)

[image: My Text Entry settings]

### Update

Unfortunately, I found the main problem is The Gnome removing features that lots of people use. This is one among many other disrespectful decisions to Gnome users. Because of it I moved from Unit (Gnome based) to another Windows Manager/Desktop Environment (Openbox) in another distro (BunsenLabs). There, I had to figure out how to edit the X settings to achieve this.

Although this, with this question I have in my mind regular Esperanto folks I try to introduce to Linux, that unlike me, they aren't comfortable with using terminal and editing config files. Unhappily, after Gnome developers choosing to drop users access to configure their input as they need, there is no easy way to do that after Ubuntu 14.04 without terminal hacking or installing external tweaking programs. I don't know well Linux Mint, but Cinnamon seems to preserve this feature.

Besides this, I chosen one right answer as it seems to do the job, and is something a Linux novice would be able to handle.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I type accentuated characters like ë?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/358/how-can-i-type-accentuated-characters-like-%c3%ab)

Comment: @DavidFoerster It's not duplicate. First: To set up the compose key I need to open the Options button to, which is the missing button I'm looking for. Second: In Esperanto you need circumflex in characters like C, G, J and S. You can't produce them with a normal keyboard. You need the `Adding Esperanto Circumflexes (Supersigno)` to they became avaliable. Checkout this if you want more info: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Esperanto_orthography

Comment: I have a normal English (UK) keyboard layout and can type ĉĝĵŝ with the compose key, which is Shift+AltGr by default. As for the *Options* button: try *Keyboard Settings…* instead and take it from there. I guess Canonical changed the layout and titles around a bit since the [top answer](/a/368/175814) was written.

Comment: Oh, I guess I understand the core issue now: You can't find the button as described in the two instructions. Try my suggestion and write an answer describing your findings (preferably with a screenshot) in an answer.

Comment: There are a lot of good answers here: http://esperanto.stackexchange.com/questions/378/how-do-i-type-the-letters-with-accents-on-linux/440#440

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La ebleco facile elekti 'Adding Esperanto circumflexes (supersigno)' malaperis en Ubuntu 14.04.

Ekde Ubuntu 14 vi

1) instalu 'gnome-tweak-tool' kaj

2) elektu 'Typing' (tajpado, la 2a vico plej supre) kaj

3) ŝanĝu 'Adding Esperanto Supersigned Letters' al 'To the corresponding key in a QUERTY layoyt'

Please see also other good solutions here: https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/questions/378/how-do-i-type-the-letters-with-accents-on-linux/440

Answer (score 3):

From the console I use:

```
setxkbmap -option esperanto:qwerty
```

Comment: This just sets it for the session. Next reboot you'll have to type it again. But it's possible to edit some file to make it permanent.

Answer (score 0):

I'm running Trusty, and found the place to set the Compose key right where David suggested: in `Settings/"Text Entry"/"Keyboard Settings...."/"Text Entry"/Shortcuts/Typing` (where the selections are a confusing mix of menu selections, tabs, highlighted text, selections from a list, etc).  Note that is the same settings dialog that you can get via `Setting/Keyboard/Shortcuts/Typing`.  A bit confusing....

Then I set Compose Key to "Right Alt", and now I can press "Right Alt" then shift "6" (for the "^" circumflex), then "c" and get ĉ :)